# How to use With and Values in Mysql

Tags: mysql, with-clause

I have a question, how can I use '**with clause**' with params in mysql as I used to do in postgre sql, i.e. using **with** and **values**, like below example :

Postgresql:

```
with params(idmodelo) as (values(10))
select * from modelo where idmodelo  = (select idmodelo from params)
```

Comment: `with params as (SELECT 10 AS idmodelo) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VALUES statement is implemented in MySQL 8.0.19 and later. If you use an earlier version, you must upgrade.

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.32    |
+-----------+

mysql> with params(idmodelo) as (values row(10)) 
       select * from params;
+----------+
| idmodelo |
+----------+
|       10 |
+----------+
```

For more details, read the manual entry on the [VALUES statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/values.html)